# Different behaviour of range with lodash/fp

Tags: functional-programming, lodash

The method `_.range()` with [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) has a fixed arity of two.

Basically, you can't do `_.range(4)` but with you have to do `_.range(0, 4)`.
I guess this has something to do with the functional approach.

Can someone explain or point me toward some useful resources?
Or maybe write an example that shows the advantages of using it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since lodash/fp functions are [curried](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-currying/), you need to have a fixed arity (the number of arguments a function can take), which means that the function can't have optional parameters).

**Note:** lodash (and ramda) use a more relaxed version of currying. In classic currying, the resulting function receives 1 argument at a time until the original arity is reached, and the original function is invoked. For example, for arity of 3 - `fn(arg)(arg)(arg)`. While in lodash you can supply multiple parameters (like in `_.range(0, 4)`) instead of 1. So if you've got a function with arity of 3, you can use `fn(arg, arg, arg)` or `fn(arg, arg)(arg)` or `fn(arg)(arg)(arg)`, etc... - ie all combinations that will result in 3 arguments.

If you usually use `_.range(n)` (fixed arity of 1), you can call the function with `0` - `_.range(0)`. Due to the curried nature of lodash/fp functions, you'll get a new function, that expects only a single number (the upper bound).  The function will generate a range from `0` to that number (like the standard lodash's range).

```js
const range0 = _.range(0)

console.log(range0(3))

console.log(range0(1))
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```